# Illegal quoting on line using FasterCSV in ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fastercsv

I am facing "Illegal quoting" error when parse the content from SQL dump and the dump file is in the format of TXT with tab (\t) separator.

```
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'faster_csv'
  begin
  FasterCSV.foreach(excel_file, :quote_char => '"',:col_sep =>'\t', :row_sep =>:auto, :headers => :first_row) do |row|

  col= row.to_s.split(/\t/)

  if col[3]!="" or !col[3].empty?
    color_value=col[3].to_s.capitalize
    #Inser Color
    color=Color.find_or_create_by_name(:name=>color_value)
  elsif col[3].empty?
    color_id= nil
  end

  end
  rescue Exception => e
  puts e
  end
```

The program executed and run successfully but there is an invalid data present like 
below (@font-face ...) mean execution terminated with error of "Illegal quoting on line 3.

```
    ID Name code comments
     1 white 234 good
     2 Black 222 
     3 red   343 @font-face { font-family: "Verdana"; .....}
```

Can any one suggest me how to skip when invalid data occurs in column ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve the error you are seeing, but you need to use double quotes around escaped characters, e.g.:

```
:col_sep => "\t"
```

Comment: waite Thanks! Still i am facing same issue "Illegal quoting line 3". May I know, How to skip the row, which contain same invalid data?

Answer (score 0):

FasterCSV isn't very kind to badly formatted data.
I don't know that there is a solution for this.

However - if your example file doesn't actually contain any quoting using "
then perhaps just use a different quot_char (eg ')

Comment: Thanks! I have tried with single quot char ('). but my problem is how to handle the data sheet which contain some invalid data here I have CSS code. May I know how to skip this one and continue program execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ASCII` code for the `NULL` character -- `\0x00` -- as such:

```
FasterCSV.foreach(excel_file, :quote_char => '\0x00',:col_sep =>'\t', :row_sep =>:auto, :headers => :first_row) do |row|
 ...
end
```

You can find a chart of some ASCII chars here: http://www.bluesock.org/~willg/dev/ascii.html